# Why directive attribute doesn't works on img html tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I have this directive to diplay image popup on hover:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHoverImage]'
})
export class HoverImageDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener("mouseenter") onMouseEnter(){
    let elem =  this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    const imageurl = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png"
    const imgElem = document.createElement('img');
    
    imgElem.src = imageurl;
    this.renderer.addClass(imgElem, "expand-image");
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, imgElem);
  }
}
```

Here is expand-image css class:

```
  .expand-image
  {
    margin: 150px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: scale(3); 
    z-index:999;
  }
```

Here how I use appHoverImage directive:

```
<img class="card-image" [src]="imageUrl" appHoverImage/>
```

but if I use directive on the div element:

```
<div appHoverImage></div>
```

it works perfectly.

Any idea why appHoverImage attribute doesn't works on img
element?

Comment: Because you can't append HTMLElement into `<img/>` tag. Append it to the body and make you sure you position it correctly

Comment: @yurzui, thanks for the post.
Can you please show example of how to append it to the body in the directive?

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/29kQlPPNJ8hMWGTgYe4f

Comment: @Michael i found something else and gave my answer another try.  let me know if that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the img tag cannot have child elements and you're looking to add it elsewhere

you could do something like this to access the parent node and add it as a "sibling" to the current element.

```
this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode, imgElem);
```

Comment: thanks for the post, but I get this error on the row above:

ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: i'm sorry, i think i had the parameters backwards.  i have corrected my post.  could you give that a shot?

Comment: @Michael i think i got it this time :)  let me know if this works.